# Как привязать кнопке видео?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Ребят помогите, есть две кнопки , нужно для каждой кнопке добавить видео файл. Допустим при нажатии на кнопку открывается одно видео , а при нажатии на другую кнопку на том же месте открывается другое видео

```
<div id="content">
        <video class="videoContent" id="video1_play" src="resources/1.mov"  autoplay></video> //./ первое видео
        <button>
        <img src="resources/image/btn.png"/>
        </button>
        <video class="videoContent" id="video2_play" src="resources/2.mov"  autoplay></video> //./ второе видео
        <button>
            <img src="resources/image/btn.png"/>
        </button>
    </div>
```

Comment: На jquery пишешь код, что при нажатии кнопки меняется html элемента с видео и меняешь его на нужную ссылку. Я бы написал, но занят. Почитай про jquery

Comment: @Nikita я хочу сделать на чистом javascript

Comment: можно. Прикрепи код HTML с кнопками и видео файлами

Comment: А видео вставляются через `<video>` или через `<iframe>`?

Comment: @Cheg через видео

Comment: @nikita добавил

Comment: @KAGGDesign обратите внимание, тут говорится про воспроизведение видеофайлов, а не роликов на Ютубе!

Comment: @PavelMayorov да, в самом деле. Удалил свой коммент и отозвал голос за закрытие.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var els__butLink = document.querySelectorAll('.but-link'),
    el__player = document.querySelector('#video');

// Перебираем все кнопки
els__butLink.forEach(function(el__butLink) {
  // Создаём событие нажатия на кнопку
  el__butLink.addEventListener('click', function() {
    // Получаем ссылку на видео из адрибута
    var str__video = el__butLink.getAttribute('data-video');
    
    // Меняем ссылку на видео в плеере
    el__player.src = str__video;
    // Воспроизводим видео
    el__player.play();
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <video class="videoContent" id="video" autoplay controls=""></video>
  
  <button class="but-link" data-video="resources/1.mov"><img src="resources/image/btn.png"/></button>
  <button class="but-link" data-video="resources/2.mov"><img src="resources/image/btn.png"/></button>
</div>
```

Comment: Было бы неплохо добавить пояснений.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, написал. Спасибо за замечание

Answer (score 2):

Одно видео и 2 кнопки. При нажатии он заменяет источник.

```js
function fVideo(){
document.getElementById("video1_play").setAttribute("src", "resources/1.mov");
return false;
};

function sVideo(){
document.getElementById("video1_play").setAttribute("src", "resources/2.mov");
return false;
};
```

```html
<div id="content">
        <video class="videoContent" id="video1_play" src="resources/1.mov"  autoplay></video> //./ первое видео
        <button onclick="fVideo()">
            <img src="resources/image/btn.png"/>
        </button>
        <button onclick="sVideo()">       
            <img src="resources/image/btn.png"/>
        </button>
    </div>
```

Comment: Что-то у вас функция какая-то не существующая ;)

Comment: @Visman теперь существующая

Comment: Я про это `"message": "TypeError: document.getElementsById is not a function"`

Comment: исправил ошибку. Надо было `getElementById `

Comment: @nikita видео воспроизводятся параллельно , а  надо чтобы нажав на первую кнопку открывалась первое видео и соответственно при нажатии на вторую кнопку первое видео закрывалось и открывалось на том же месте второе видео

Answer (score 0):

```
if (videoEl.paused) {
    videoEl.play();
} else {
    videoEl.pause();
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]